# Kubernetes liveness probe: can a pod monitor its own stdout?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

My idea was to implement a liveness probe as a command, and use something like

```
$ grep something ERROR
```

from inside a pod, so that if in the output of a pod, a line containing ERROR exists, the liveness probe fails.

Is this possible? If not, is it possible if I add another container in the same pod, to monitor the first container?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could query the [Kubernetes API server](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#read-log).

The request looks like this:

`GET /api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods/{name}/log`

To use the token that's usually mounted in a Pod, you can call it like this:

```sh
curl https://kubernetes/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/$HOSTNAME/log -k \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)"
```

Comment: Thank you. For completeness, I ended up adding the parameter ?sinceSeconds=<N_seconds> to the query, because otherwise it's too big.

Comment: OP Be aware that the kubernetes service host address is also available in the environment, as follows (I extended this with the sinceSeconds parameter, as proposed by @engineerX):
`curl https://${KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST}/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/${HOSTNAME}/log?sinceSeconds=<N_seconds> -k -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)"`

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can have more then one container per pod. It's just not a standard approach because it violate the "one process per container" principle. You can read this [article](https://linchpiner.github.io/k8s-multi-container-pods.html) explaining multi-container pods in Kubernetes, what are the use cases and so on.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: 1st
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: html
      mountPath: /tmp/html
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - cat
        - /tmp/html/test
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 3
  - name: 2nd
    image: debian
    volumeMounts:
    - name: html
      mountPath: /tmp/html
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    args:
      - while true; do
          date >> /tmp/html/test;
          sleep 5;
        done
  volumes:
  - name: html
    emptyDir: {}
```

In this example `pod` have two containers. Container `1st` running `nginx` with mounted `/tmp/html` and `livenessProbe` which after 10 seconds from start checks if file `/tmp/html/test` exists every 3 seconds and if it's missing it restarts the container. And `2nd`container running `debian` with `/tmp/html/` mounted, but it is also adding data entry into file `/tmp/html/test` each 5 seconds.

In the above example if you remove the file manually and probe caches it it will restart `1st` container.

You would have to tailor this example into your particular needs, for example use `grep -q ERROR /tml/html/test` which if succeed removes the `/tmp/html/test` or change the probe itself.